# Set foreignkey field based on request

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using the Django Rest Framework 3.2. I have a model "Report" with a ForeignKey to the model "Office".

I want to set the `report.office` based on the request.

This is how I did it (which I don't like, because it requires duplication):

In my view I differ between GET or POST/PUT/PATCH requests, where GET uses a nested Serializer representation, and POST/PUT/PATCH uses flat serializer representations.

Then I do in my view:

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.save(office=Office.objects.get_only_one_from_request(self.request))
```

and in my FlatOfficeSerializer:

```
def validate(self, attrs):
    if self.instance is not None:
        instance = self.instance
        instance_fields = instance._meta.local_fields
        for f in instance_fields:
            f = self.get_initial().get(f.name)
    else:
        instance = self.Meta.model(**attrs)
    request = self.context.get('request')
    instance.office = Office.objects.get_only_one_from_request(request)
    instance.clean()
    return attrs
```

It is clear that there is a duplication there and although it is working I don't like it. Without the duplication the validation fails (of course) on the `instance.clean()`, which calls the clean method of the model. I really need this, because my business logic is in the model's clean and save methods.

Comment: Can you post little more details. I can help. Why don't  you use managers method.

Comment: Set the nested serializer attributes to read_only so they won't be taken into account when editing or creating new instances.

Comment: @seenus thank you for you idea. It might be good, but I don't know how to implement his.

Comment: @dukebody The nested vs flat serializers is not the problem -> The problem is setting a foreignKey based on information of the request, instead of letting the user give this information.

Comment: The DRF tutorial has an example about setting the snippet author to the logged in user. It does so by setting the field as read only and setting the value in the perform_create method as you do. This way model validation won't fail.

Comment: Ah, sorry! This is of course the way to do it! A BIG thank you!

Comment: This is the obvious way to do this, but it does not work. Why, because I need to use the instance.clean() on my validation, which will raise an error that there is no stable object...

Comment: Can you follow this link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/ and write custom managers methods

Comment: Can you call the instance.clean by overriding the model save(). try this.